# Mocha.js --recursive tests fail, but fine as individuals

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js

I've got mocha.opts like this:

```
test/mocha/*.js
--recursive
--globals reactModulesToStub
--check-leaks
--compilers .:test/jsx-compiler.js
--reporter nyan
```

and there are two tests that pass when called individually, but fail with the recursive option.  Am I missing something?

For example, if I run mocha on this single test, no problem, but adding a similar test to the same directory will cause all tests to fail.

```jsx
/** @jsx React.DOM */
//tests/app/loginstatus-test.js

var React = require('react/addons'),
    assert = require('assert'),
    sinon = require('sinon'),
    stubs = (function(){
        global.reactModulesToStub = [
            'TestClass.js'
        ];
    })(),
    MyComponent = require('../../app/modules/LoginStatus.jsx'),
    TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils,
    TestContext = require('./../lib/TestContext').getRouterComponent(MyComponent),
    component = TestContext.component,
    dom = TestContext.dom,
    flux = TestContext.flux;

describe('LoginStatus', function() {

    it('renders the LoginStatus class', function() {
        TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(
            component, 'LoginStatus');
    });

    it('when mounted and clicked, should call AppActions.showPopupModal', function() {
        sinon.spy(flux.actions.AppActions, "showPopupModal");
        TestUtils.Simulate.click(component.refs.loginStatusText.getDOMNode());
        assert(flux.actions.AppActions.showPopupModal.calledOnce);
    });
});
```

Comment: Do both tests have lines like `global.reactModulesToStub`? Those are both running at load time, so they will conflict.

Comment: @loganfsmyth thanks, yes they are both running at load time.  here's my solution https://github.com/adjavaherian/mocha-react

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a namespace issue.  I didn't realize that Mocha clubbed all the describes into the same namespace, if you need clean variables between tests, scope them into `it();`  Here's a great example of how to do what I was trying to do before.

https://github.com/adjavaherian/mocha-react